# How to link to native libraries in a Visual Studio Code project?

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-code, glfw, glew

I am learning OpenGl and I am new to ms Visual Studio Code. I want to add GLEW and GLFW to visual studio code. I have been only able to add header files and it's been 2 weeks from then and I still haven't been able to figure out how to add libraries of GLEW and GLFW to vscode.  All the tutorials on the Internet are made for past versions of the visual studio by creating an empty project. But this empty project option is not available in Visual Studio Code. So, please help me to figure this out.

I have added header files in c_cpp_properties.json.
But I don't know how to add libraries.

Comment: First determine what you are using `Visual Studio 2020` or `Visual Studio Code`. `Visual Studio Code 2020` does not exist

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: Use a build tool like Make or CMake

Comment: How? can you share the link?

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to use cmake.

Comment: After reading this and with the help of some websites I tried linking GLFW but it isn't working and still, I have no idea how to link GLEW. :(

Comment: *Update* Just a few minutes ago  I was able to successfully link GLFW with my project. :)